# Php Curl HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I try to send request (Post Request) To url but it return

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
content-disposition: attachment; filename=json.json
content-length: 118
content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8
date: Sat, 02 Sep 2017 11:33:56 GMT
server: tsa_o
strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519
vary: Origin
x-connection-hash: 32931e6376249fb1689df3203e847a2b
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-response-time: 108
x-transaction: 0021b7c8005c6a4e
x-tsa-request-body-time: 1
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

{"capsError":"insufficientpermission","requestId":"4f0c87b1349996812fafe51ca6a8197b5bb1e9d560d7dcb8a450ab
  3c890e40ac"}

my code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $URL,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'postField',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR =>  realpath("cookies/" . $name . ".txt"),
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => realpath("cookies/" . $name . ".txt"),
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT=>30,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,      // return headers                       
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>true,
));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close( $ch );
return $output;
```

Iam Sure From All post Field But The Same Response Return 
But in browser Every Thing is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can change `$output = curl_exec($ch);` to `echo $output = curl_exec($ch);` .This way you will see error messages in your browser.

Also, try urlencode($url); in case your url has some white spaces in it.

But Your problem is most likely the security of the target server.Lots of servers treat cURL like cross site forgery attacks.This is why any cURL script must contain the csrf token of the target page to it's post parameters.

You must first locate the token from your target page and then write code so that your script will parse the token out of the curl_exec output string.

Comment: Thanks For Replay This is the returned Value    `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
content-disposition: attachment; filename=json.json
content-length: 118
content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8
date: Sat, 02 Sep 2017 12:34:26 GMT
server: tsa_o
strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519
vary: Origin
x-connection-hash: ee1dbbca70af69c7815edcb505d16533
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-response-time: 107
x-transaction: 00d500270066af4b
x-tsa-request-body-time: 1
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block`

Comment: `{"capsError":"insufficient permission","requestId":"6bcb762e8d2c9039b0eb715f252944924fb2cd90ef3174503d65fe464acb2d87"}`

Comment: @Looper Answer my question or I wont be able to help you.Have you used cURL to login to your url?

Comment: Yes I Login To The System Via Curl And i reuse the cookies Which I Saved In files To send this request

Comment: @Looper         Set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>false and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>false

Comment: Same Response Please See My Above Comment

Answer (score 0):

You can always rewrite your code.

something like this :

```
 $http_headers = array(
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36',);

 $crl = curl_init();
 $url = "http://www.example.gr/node/add/content";
 curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
 curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt"); 
 curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
 curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_headers);
 curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
 curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36");
 curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);

 echo $result=curl_exec($crl);
 curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 $postdata = array(
    "title_field[und][0][value]"=>"category",
    "op"=>"Save",     );
 curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
 echo $result=curl_exec($crl);
```

Many things could have gone wrong with your version.If this doesn't work recheck what I wrote in my first anwer.

Comment: can we talk in skype?

Comment: @Looper       Here is what you ll do.1)Open the target url with firefox(not chrome).2)press ctl+SHIFT+i 3)go to the network tab 4)with the console still open fill the input yourself and click save. 4)when post request is made you ll see it on the console, cllick it and go to parameters.5)check for the long string, could be named form_id or form_token id

Comment: ok the param i checked it the same the header request want x-csrf-token nothing in the page except authication_token i try to send it as header in the post request same response do you have skype ?

Comment: @Looper        Can you share the url of the page, maybe I would be able to help you.No time for skype.

Comment: @Looper  What do you mean by auto vote.What would your app do?

Comment: @Looper cURL wasn't really made for voting but I guess it could work.The csrf certficte you see from the browser belongs to the browser wich means its uselless for the curl wich runs on server.The correct csrf is inside the $output string wich contains the html code of the url.first you must make a culr_exex withoud data just to retreive it and curl_exec again with data and token.I am warning you, this can be seen as hacking and dont try it on anything more serious than votes or you could be arrested.Good luck.

Comment: @Looper no problem,consider marking my answer as correct since that's what it was

Comment: @Looper  Hey, How's it going? did you made it?

Comment: Yes I Success Thank You For Your Help The Problem In Sending Header And I Fixed It Now